# winsound import error

Tags: python

I just got my RPi and it used to be able to play tones with winsound.  Now, I get an error when I try to import it.  Do I have to reimage?

File "/home/pi/Py_Progs/tones1.py", line 1, in 
    import winsound
ImportError: No module named 'winsound'

Answer (score 3):

From https://docs.python.org/2/library/winsound.html :

> 35.4. winsound — Sound-playing interface for Windows

The Raspberry Pi is not a Windows computer, it is a Linux computer. You will need to use a different sound library to be able to play sounds from Python on the RPi.

These questions over on our sister site StackOverflow give some options:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12354586/python-what-are-the-nearest-linux-and-osx-equivalents-of-winsound-beep

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13150267/convert-winsound-to-a-linux-platform

The best recommendation I have been able to get from a quick search is to utilize the `pygame` module instead of `winsound`, like so (courtesy of the accepted answer in the second StackOverflow link above):

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

pygame.mixer.music.load("ding.wav")

pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

Comment: When I first got the RPi it would play sounds with winsound.  Now I get an error importing it.  I can't get sounds from anywhere now.  Even SonicPi doesn't work.  I can import pygame but no noise when I run the script you provided.  Must be something else like maybe even hardware.  I'll keep fooling around.  How much can I mess it up anyway?  Thanks for answering.